# pytz: getting all timezones, where now is between a specific range of times

Tags: python, timezone, list-comprehension, python-datetime, pytz

I'm trying to get a list of timezones which are within a set range of local times. E.g. between 9am and 2pm.

Following on from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947115/pytz-getting-all-timezones-where-now-specific-time) question it is possible to get timezones for a specific time e.g. 9am but I wanted a range.

Short of doing this for every hour like follows, is there a better way to accomplish this?

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

now = datetime.now(pytz.utc)
[tz for tz in pytz.common_timezones_set if now.astimezone(pytz.timezone(tz)).hour == 9]
[tz for tz in pytz.common_timezones_set if now.astimezone(pytz.timezone(tz)).hour == 10]
[tz for tz in pytz.common_timezones_set if now.astimezone(pytz.timezone(tz)).hour == 11]
...
```

Comment: can you use inequalities? e.g. `(now.astimezone(pytz.timezone(tz)).hour >= 9) and (now.astimezone(pytz.timezone(tz)).hour <= 11)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) used in the `if` clause of a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) (that's being used in the answer to the linked question) can be as complex as needed as shown below.

Note I have also modified how the time comparison is done so it no longer ignores the minutes, seconds, and microseconds of the converted value which assumes that the time change difference will always be in whole hours. While that's generally true, there are at least a couple of exceptions I know of (and there could be more in the future).

Also note that the time interval itself is not limited to a whole number of hours — so for instance a time range of `begin, end = time(hour=9, minute=0), time(hour=9, minute=30)` could also be checked.

```
from datetime import datetime, time
from pprint import pprint
import pytz

def datetime_to_time(dt, tz):
    """Convert datetime dt to timezone tz and return its local time of day."""
    ndt = dt.astimezone(pytz.timezone(tz))
    return time(hour=ndt.hour, minute=ndt.minute, second=ndt.second,
                microsecond=ndt.microsecond)

begin, end = time(hour=9), time(hour=10)  # Time range.
now = datetime.now(pytz.utc)
in_time_range = [tz for tz in pytz.common_timezones_set if
                        begin <= datetime_to_time(now, tz) <= end]

print('in_time_range:')
pprint(in_time_range)
```